# How to turn off validation in Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, validation, html, nokogiri

I need to insert HTML 5 video tag to some places of HTML document, being parsed with Nokogiri.

Since it does't supports HTML 5 (afaik), it throws an exception, because the document is not valid in terms of HTML 4.0.

Is it possible to switch the validation off ?

Comment: Are you using the HTML parser? Because it doesn't validate by default.

Comment: I just parsed a few html 5 pages with no problem.

Answer (score 4):

It would help if you would show some sample code demonstrating the problem, along with the error you are seeing.

Nokogiri should parse HTML fine as it uses a lenient mode for HTML. I switched to Nokogiri several years ago because I had some HTML and RSS feeds that caused Hpricot to explode. Nokogiri would occasionally get mad because a page was full of errors, but at least the were ways to get at it. Rescue the exception, then check your [`doc.errors`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Document.html) to see what Nokogiri thinks the problem is.

Something like this should help:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML('<html><body>...</body></html>')
puts doc.errors if (doc.errors.any?)
...
```